# 'Cannot put Window in Style' error even though the view is in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a small countdown app in WPF. My MainWindow should be used merely for using `<ContentPresenter/>` , but it doesn't seem to work- it comes up with the Cannot put Windows in Style error.

This has never happened before using this same approach.

My MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="CountdownTimer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CountdownTimer"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:CountdownTimer.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CountdownTimer.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:ApplicationViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:CountdownViewModel}">
        <views:CountdownView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
```

CountdownView is the view containing the countdown UI. CountdownViewModel is the Viewmodel controlling the countdown system. ApplicationView defines CurrentView as a CountdownViewModel and sets it to an instance of CountdownViewModel in its constructor.

Comment: please, provide full code

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, I had already used the DataTemplate that was the answer to the other post. This is a different issue.

Comment: Also the full code is long and unimportant. I kept it to the important file for brevity.

Comment: Sorry it was indeed a duplicate I misread the other post, didn't realise that using a usercontrol was part of the answer in that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved. I was using an actual window instead of a user control. I set up a new view  (user control) to test and it worked, so I double checked the view I wanted and it was actually a window.

Use usercontrols not windows for new views.